# Are examples from RFC4475 available as C++ source strings?

Tags: c, sip

RFC 4475 contains a number of "hard to parse" SIP messages.

Are they available somewhere as C/C++ source code?

(If I was to convert them myself there are too many special cases with `"` and `\` so I bound to create bugs in the test-source.)

Comment: `If I was to convert them myself` Every good text editor has a search&replace tool. There are also tools that allow to include the content of a file or to convert a file to a C source code, like `xxd`. Why would you ever want to "search" for them?

Comment: Probably not. Why would they be?

Comment: I started looking at the search-replace, but I soon realized that there where too many special cases in the RFC text.   
And the reason is simple, I prefer handling data as code-member rather than readin data from file. Personal preference.